# Display the markup in an xml file on the CruiseControl.NET dashboard

Tags: xml, xslt, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to display the contents of my xml file on CC dashboard.

Specifically, I would like to display data on this page:

_http://server/CCNet/server/local/project/TestApplication

This is the page that shows the results of the most recent build. At this point anything will do. Either get the data from within the elements of my xml file, or just render the whole xml file.

Even a link to my xml file somewhere on the dashboard would do.

I've tried modifying the header.xsl file on the server, but so far all I can do is display what I hard code in header.xsl, not data from my xml file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to see a different xml for each build, or is this a static xml file that should always be available?

If it is static, you can use the [externalLinks](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/External+Links) node to your project.

If you have a unique xml per build, you will need to do the following:

1. [Merge](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/File+Merge+Task) the xml into your build output.
2. Create an xsl and place it on your build server (usually under \webdashboard\xsl folder)
3. In the dashboard.config, add your xsl as an xslReportBuildPlugin

Comment: Thank you! Steps 1 and 2 did the trick. I did not do step 3 as I was modifying the xsl in header.xsl, which is already added in dashboard.config.